# Setting default value from database in JQuery datetimer picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried date time picker in my application with help of the following program:

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It worked fine.

My problem is, I need to set default value for date time fetched from database.

```
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date" >
<input type="text"></input>    
<span class="add-on">
<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

When I tried to set the value as:

```
<input type="text" value="<%=datetimefromdatabase%>"></input>
```

it didn't worked.
Kindly help.

Comment: $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults = { defaultDate:"...", ...};

Comment: @Ferret: this will set `defaultDate` for all instances i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can set like this

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").setDate("10/23/2013");
```

Please read the documentation fully.